# A struct that contains two double pointers, seg faults when accessing second double pointer

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault, double-pointer

I am trying to access the second double pointer but it immediately seg faults only after accessing the first one. What is going on?

It seems to work without the second double pointer but I have no idea why.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct queue{
    int ** x;
    int ** y;
};

struct queue funct1(){
    struct queue me;
    int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int * y = malloc(sizeof(int));

    *x = 20;
    *y = 40;
    me.x = &x; 
    me.y = &y;
    return me;
}


int main(void){
    struct queue hello;

    hello = funct1();

    printf("%d\n", *(*(hello.x)));
    printf("%d\n", *(*(hello.y)));
}
```

Expected:
20
40

Actual:
20
Segmentation fault: 11

EDIT:

It still doesnt seem to work. I have added this code to the function:

```
    int ** xpointer = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    int ** ypointer = malloc(sizeof(int*));

    *x = 20;
    *y = 40;
    xpointer = &x;
    ypointer = &y;

    me.x = xpointer; 
    me.y = ypointer;
```

EDIT 2: This seems to work.

```
struct queue funct1(){
    struct queue me;
    int * x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int * y = malloc(sizeof(int));

    int ** xpointer = malloc(sizeof(int*));
    int ** ypointer = malloc(sizeof(int*));

    *x = 20;
    *y = 40;
    *xpointer = x;
    *ypointer = y;

    me.x = xpointer; 
    me.y = ypointer;

    return me;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain your intended purpose in using the double pointer in the first place?

Comment: Assignment specifications tell us to return a struct that contains a pointer variable and a double pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pointers to a function's local variables are no longer valid once a function exits, but your `funct1` function is saving such pointers in places where they'll be used later. In particular, it's invalid to access both `*(hello.x)` and `*(hello.y)` after `funct1` returns, and it's only by coincidence that the first works.

Comment: Is there any solution around this? Should I malloc(sizeof(int *)), so that I can return the struct properly?

Comment: That's because you're not actually using what you malloc'd; you're immediately leaking it and then using the local again anyway.

Comment: Can you recommend and good resources for me to definitively understand pointers in C? I have been working in C for some time now and it is frustrating that I still find double pointers confusing.

Comment: @Work_Work Unfortunately, those kinds of recommendations are off-topic here.